# How to use an ActionListener to make a JPanel Visible

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I tried to make the first JPanel disappear and the second JPanel visible with the click of a JButton.
So far i only get the first JPanel to show and after clicking the JButton the Frame gets empty.
I also tried to do it with composition so i dont have to extend classes. So my bad understanding of how
composition works might be the problem. I looked into it alot but couldnt find a proper solution for my problem.

First JPanel class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel1 {

JPanel firstscreenpanel = new JPanel();
JButton jButton1 = new JButton();
    
Panel1() {
    
    jButton1.setBounds(300,300,400,200);
    jButton1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    jButton1.setVisible(true);
    jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    Panel2 test = new Panel2();
            
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        
            firstscreenpanel.setVisible(false); 
            test.secondscreenpanel.setVisible(true);
            
            
            }
    });
    
    
}

public Component panelone() {
    
    firstscreenpanel.setSize(1280, 1024);
    firstscreenpanel.setLayout(null);
    firstscreenpanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    firstscreenpanel.add(jButton1);
    firstscreenpanel.setVisible(true);
    return firstscreenpanel;
            
    }

}
```

Second JPanel class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel2 {

public JPanel secondscreenpanel = new JPanel();
public JButton jButton2 = new JButton();



Panel2() {
    
    jButton2.setBounds(100,100,400,200);
    jButton2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    jButton2.setVisible(true);
            
}
    
public Component paneltwo() {
    
    secondscreenpanel.setSize(1280, 1024);
    secondscreenpanel.setLayout(null);
    secondscreenpanel.add(jButton2);
    secondscreenpanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    secondscreenpanel.setVisible(false);
    return secondscreenpanel;
            
    }
    }
```

JFrame Class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame1 {


public JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
Panel1 panel1 = new Panel1();
Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();

Frame1() {
    
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.setState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame1.setSize(1280, 1024);
    frame1.setLayout(null);
    frame1.add(panel1.panelone());
    frame1.add(panel2.paneltwo());
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    
            
    }
    }
```

Main Class:

```
    public class MainClass {

        
    private void showGUI() {

    Frame1 jframe = new Frame1();
                        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final MainClass main = new MainClass();
        
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()

          {
            public void run() {
                main.showGUI();

            }
        
         });
        
      }

        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you are creating a new Panel2 object and you aren't using the object from your original JFrame. You should probably pass a reference of your JFrame to your panel1 so that you can then use the jpanel2 from the referenced Jframe

Comment: I dont really unterstand how to pass a reference of my JFrame hm.

Comment: your JPanel should have a JFrame in it and then you can pass the JFrame into the constructor of your JPanel when the JPanel is being created.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix your program by passing a reference of your frame to your panel1. See my example below.

**Frame class**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame1 {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private Panel1 panel1;
    private Panel2 panel2;

    Frame1() {
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
         frame.setSize(1280, 1024);
         frame.setLayout(null);
         panel1 = new Panel1(this);
         frame.add(panel1.getPanel());
         panel2 = new Panel2();
         frame.add(panel2.getPanel());
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Panel2 getPanel2() {
        return panel2;
    }

}
```

**Panel1 class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Panel1 {
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private Frame1 frame1;
    private JButton jButton1 = new JButton();

    public Panel1(Frame1 frame1) {
        this.frame1 = frame1;
        panel.setSize(1280, 1024);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        panel.add(jButton1);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        jButton1.setBounds(300,300,400,200);
        jButton1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jButton1.setVisible(true);
        jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                panel.setVisible(false);
                frame1.getPanel2().getPanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
         return panel;
    }
}
```

**Panel2 class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Panel2 {
     private JButton jButton2 = new JButton();
     private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public Panel2() {
        panel.setSize(1280, 1024);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(jButton2);
        panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        panel.setVisible(false);

        jButton2.setBounds(100,100,400,200);
        jButton2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jButton2.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() {
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Comment: changed my answer to remove any extending classes

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what i was searching for!

Answer (score 1):

I did not check the whole code (too bug, too many <sub>empty</sub> lines) but stopped at `Panel2 test = new Panel2();`

is this instance being added to some visible component? if not it will never be displayed.

Note: using a `null` layout manager is often not recommended, use a `CardLayout` or even a `JTabbedPane` to switch components - see tutorial [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Ye maybe thats the Problem. I did that because i thaught i need to do that in order to access the second panel inside the actionlistener.

Comment: but `new ....` is creating a new instance, does not help to access the other instance. Or pass the instance in constructor (not so good), or use listeners (better?), or the correct components (see note in answer)

Comment: Alright i will look into CardLayout and hope that i can solve my problem. Thx for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best implementation, but it is simple enough for you to follow. I modified your code to create a frame containing your original two panels (although those panel classes are not necessary - as I explained in a comment on your posted solution), and a button to toggle visibility on the panels. I am using a regular `JButton` and not a `JToggleButton` also not the best use of the class, but simply for you to understand.

The Action Listener is added to the button on the frame. Notice that my action listener does not create new instances of anything. That was part of the original problem. Since the button is a member of the frame class like the panels 1 and 2, it has access to them directly. SO, in the listener, all I need to do is "toggle" the visibility of each of the panels.

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    private Panel1 panel1 = new Panel1();
    private Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();
    private JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton button = new JButton("Toggle");

    public Frame1() {
    
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                boolean visible = panel1.isVisible();
                panel1.setVisible(!visible);
                panel2.setVisible(visible);
            
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setSize(1280, 1024);
        btnPanel.setSize(400, 100);
        btnPanel.add(button);
        setLayout(null);
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);
        add(btnPanel);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel {

    public Panel1() {
        setBounds(100,100,400,200);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Panel2 extends JPanel {

    public Panel2() {
        setBounds(100,100,400,200);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MainClass {

    private void showGUI() {

        Frame1 jframe = new Frame1();
        jframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final MainClass main = new MainClass();
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                main.showGUI();

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it definitly helps. I guess iam just abit confused because most recommendations i read on here, on how to organize a GUI project, said that i shouldnt extend classes. They said to mostly use composition and only use extending classes(inheritance) in rare overwrite cases. They also recommended creating a class for every JPanel and put all the components of that JPanel into it. Also my project has alot of JButtons and ActionListener so i guess putting them into the JFrame class will make the class really big which i wanna avoid because i did that before.

Comment: Right... in this example, you don't need `Panel1` or `Panel2`. You could simply use two instances of `JPanel` to do the same, like I used `JPanel` for my button panel. An indicator of a class not being needed is look how "empty" both of those classes are in the example I posted. A new class in the hierarchy should be implementing new behaviors. Instead, these panel classes add nothing (no new methods). An subclass should be a more specialized form of its parent. For example, a `JPanel` is a more specialized form of `JComponent`. Do you understand better now?

Comment: Its so rough as a java beginner to express myself. Iam sry. But i get what you are saying these JPanel classes are not needed because they could just be handle like you did with the btnpanel. Iam just worried because if i dont understand how to not put most of my Components in the JFrame class and still have them connected then i end up with a huge class again. I guess i suck at explaining my problem iam sry

Comment: This is a tutorial from Java Oracle that I think you should go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/. It will cover the basics you need to know to build simple GUIs with Java Swing.

Comment: Also, if my answer is what you were looking for, I will appreciate it if you mark it as such.

Comment: It sadly isnt what i was looking for. But i guess i need to change my question to make it more clear. The reason i tried to give the ActionListener in the JPanel2 class everything it needs to function was too not have to put it into the JFrame class. Thats why iam looking for a way to organize my whole project differently so i dont end up putting to much code into one class. My projects contains a big amount of Panels, Buttons and methods, so i lost overview over time because i had most of it in one class.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding "public static" to "Panel2 panel2 = new Panel2();"

And then i just used:

"Frame1.panel2.secondscreenpanel.setVisible(true);"

inside the JButton ActionListener.

Its now working but i guess thats a bad way of doing it. Because i heard that using to much static isnt that good. But i dont now why yet.

Comment: Do you know what a `static` member is? It means the member is shared among all instances of a given class. This is neither good or bad. What makes it good or bad is its applicability. Think of a `Car` class that has `Engine` as a member of the class. There is a difference between having all cars sharing a single engine (`static`) and just having identical engines (non-static with same value). Only you can determine if having a field as `static` is good or bad for your specific requirements.

Comment: For your specific problem, making `panel2` as a `static` member seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? What Problem will i get later on if i stay with it?

Comment: It is a bad idea for the reason I mentioned in the first comment. I am sure you don't want THE EXACT same "static" panel be in all different instances of your frame. Also, Panel1 and Panel2 are basically the same class with different internal values. Going to my `Car` example, if I need a blue car and a red car, I don't need to create two classes (i.e. `BlueCar` and `RedCar`). I just create a single class and provide a mechanism to create instances with different colors.

Comment: Alright i see, then i just need learn how to do it proper. Thanks

Comment: I just posted a fix to your code. Again, not the most correct implementation. Just functional to make you understand.